# Get mapped value from Key in groovy

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I have a map that I have printed, and I can see the values in it plain as day:

```
searchMatch.each {
    println("The match: " + it.employee.employeeID)
    int empID = Integer.parseInt(it.employee.employeeID);
    println("empID:" + empID)
    println("parsedResults: " + parsedResults)
    println("parsedResults[empID]: " + parsedResults[empID])
}
```

And the output is something like:

```
The match: 0518
empID:518
parsedResults: [518:[id:518, emp_name:Derek, title:Software Engineer ]]
parsedResults[empID]: null
```

So what's going on here? I am guessing I am using some wrong type for the key, but I just dont know how this is supposed to work in groovy really. If someone can explain whats going wrong here I'd appreciate it

Comment: What are the types of `empID` and the key in `parsedResults`?

Comment: parsedResults is a groovyRowResult from a sql.rows() so I am guessing string? employeeID is a string. I have tried to force it by saying parsedResults[518] and parsedResults["518"] etc and I cant get it to find the values

Comment: I'd probably *check* the type instead of guessing, just in case ;)

Comment: My money is on GString/String/Integer combo

Comment: Hrmm. Interesting. The keytype is "BigDecimal" so I guess that explains it

Comment: @Derek Yep; always check types--just because things *look* the same, doesn't mean they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as it turns out, the returned type for an "int" from a sql.rows() is a BigDecimal for the key. This is what was causing my comparisons to always come back false. I converted my string type of employee ID to a BigDecimal and it worked.

Comment: SO made me wait a couple of days. It's kind of weird that this is explicitly required. You'd think Groovy would take care of this for you.